# Clojure - Test to ensure not holding onto head?

Tags: testing, clojure

I am new to Clojure, and don't have a lot of Java experience.

I'm working on a system that is built around functions that transform one or more input lazy sequences into a new lazy sequence.  For example, a function that takes two sequences and produces a lazy sequence of the "diff" between the inputs.

In the test cases I verify that the sequences are *realized?* at the appropriate time, but I can't figure out how to verify that I haven't "held onto head" somewhere, other than to operate on a huge sequence and wait for an OutOfMemoryError.  I don't care for that approach, as "huge sequence" is arbitrary and the tests take a long time to run.

I've looked for info about the Java Garbage Collector, but couldn't find what I was looking for (or didn't understand it).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to store off a [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to a seq and then at some point later, after all references to the seq should have been discarded, force a garbage collection, dereference the WeakReference via `.get` and see that it's cleared. For instance:

```
(let [r (atom nil)
      s (atom nil)]
  (let [x (repeat 1000 1)]
    (reset! r (java.lang.ref.WeakReference. x))
    (reset! s (map (partial * 2) x)))

  ;; the lazy seq created by map has not yet been realized.
  (is (false? (realized? @s)))

  ;; Request garbage collection.
  (System/gc)

  ;; since it's not realized, the result from map still has a reference
  ;; to the head of its input seq.
  (is (false? (nil? (.get @r))))

  ;; Realize the seq returned from map.
  (dorun @s)
  (is (realized? @s))

  ;; Request garbage collection again.
  (System/gc)

  ;; Once the result from map has been realized, it should discard its reference
  ;; to the head of the input seq.
  (is (nil? (.get @r))))
```

Be warned, though, testing anything related to garbage collection and memory allocation in Java is an inexact science, because that stuff is managed asynchronously by the JVM. In particular, `System.gc()` only *suggests* that the JVM do garbage collection; there's no guarantee that the weak reference will have been cleared when that method returns, so this test is subject to spurious failures. Many style checkers will flag calls to `System.gc()` as "voodoo" for just this reason.

In general, you're best served by writing solid code, and debugging in a profiler such as [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) only when it becomes apparent that you have a memory leak.

Comment: That is cool, and the example is great, but the shaky non-promise of (System/gc) is frustrating...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's about the best you have to work with in Java. From a language design standpoint, it makes sense to under-specify things like GC behavior, or else you might prevent implementations from making otherwise useful optimizations. I've seen applications do things like put calls to System.gc() inside loops to account for the fact that its effects might not be immediately visible.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way to monitor GC eligibility of objects is to use some `java.lang.ref` reference type, preferably a [`PhantomReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html), together with a [`ReferenceQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html).

`PhantomReference`s differ from other `java.lang.ref` classes in that they *cannot* be used to get hold of the target of the reference; they are only useful together with `ReferenceQueue`s. Additionally, objects are considered phantom reachable only after they've been finalized.

The boilerplate looks like so:

```
(def rq (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.))
(def pref (java.lang.ref.PhantomReference. [1 2] rq))
(future (.remove rq 0) (println :done))
(System/gc)
;;=> :done
```

The last line shows the printout from the future.

I've got a small library which is supposed to handle the boilerplate, but alas, it seems to be in need of some maintenance work... I'll try and get around to it soon and post a link once it's done.

Comment: I was not aware of PhatomReference or ReferenceQueue.  Those are interesting.  (System/gc) is still a weak link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`(.totalMemory (Runtime/getRuntime))` will track the total memory size being used by the jvm.

Checking the allocated memory, storing the value, running your code on a multi thousand element sequence, and then checking the allocated memory again should get what you want.

Perhaps there is a way you could reduce the default size, and the granularity of allocation, in order to check memory usage increase in unit tests.